# Programa para calcular media

Tags: c, loop, float

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    int times = 0;

    int number;
    int average;

    while ( number != 9999 ){

        printf( " Type the number and i will make the average, 9999 to end:\n ");
        scanf("%d", &number);
        times = times + 1;
        sum = number + sum;
    }
    average = (float)sum/times;
    printf("The average is %f", average);
    return 0;
}
```

Quando rodo esse programa, average está me retornando -1 para qualquer input. gostaria de calcular a media da soma de (n) numeros e caso o usuario não deseje mais seguir em frente ele usa o sentinel 9999 para sair do loop e finalizar o programa.

Answer (score 2):

Testei aqui, o que estava acontecendo é que sua variável average foi inicializada como int, então depois você tava tentando colocar um float numa variavel int.

Pra facilitar, eu troquei o tipo da variavel average pra float (nao faz sentido inicializar como int) e ao inves do typecasting explicito (float) eu usei um typecast implicito, multiplicando o times por 1.0,  o que o torna um float, antes da divisao.

Aqui funcionou, teste aí e qualquer dúvida tento te explicar melhor o que tava acontecendo, mas acho que é um erro bem pequeno mesmo.

Ah, e você tem mais um problema, que quando voce insere o 9999, ele tava sendo calculado junto na media, eu adicionei um check dentro do while pra prevenir isso. (deve ter um jeito mais elegante, mas fiz simples so pra deixar a resposta correta)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    int times = 0;

    int number;
    float average;

    while ( number != 9999 ){

        printf( " Type the number and i will make the average, 9999 to end:\n ");
        scanf("%d", &number);
        if(number != 9999) {
            times = times + 1;
            sum = number + sum;
        }
    }
    average =  sum/ (times * 1.0);
    printf("The average is %f", average);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1. Mas outro problema é que ele soma o 9999 no cálculo da média. O ideal é usar um `do-while` ou checar a condição de término para não fazer a soma dela.

Comment: @LuizVieira corrigi isso agora, tb percebi o erro. Obrigado :D Grandes mentes pensam igual

Comment: Valeu cara! funcionou aqui, obrigado por notar o erro no loop também.

Comment: @VitorMatos se a resposta resolveu o seu problema não esqueça de marcá-la como solução, para que outras pessoas também possam ser ajudadas!

Comment: Acho que o typecasting explicito (float) ficaria mais fácil (ou rápido) de entender. Mas é preferência pessoal :-)